# How system give me negative number?

Tags: java

```
for(int i = 0;i<=33;i++){
        System.out.println(i+" "+(i<<i)+" "+Integer.toBinaryString(1<<i));
        //31 -2147483648 10000000000000000000000000000000
    }
```

When `i`become 31 it give me a negative number,if it's because out of bound , then what happened at that time? thanks a lot!

Comment: This must be a duplicate, but what is happening is that at `i=31` you start flipping the sign bit of that integer.  Hence, it appears negative.

Comment: [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: The top bit of a *signed* int is the sign. The sign has to be represented somehow.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I know that, but it's still not very clear.